# How to zoom Image and draw Polygon in JavaFX using

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-2, javafx-8

I  am trying to make a program to draw polygon on Image and we can zoom Image and polygon after clicking on zoom button.
After clicking on zoom button, image crops. To avoid this issue, I am using stackpane.

I tried to set X and Y Scale of AnchorPane, this perfectly able to zoom both Image and polygon but polygon is not perfectly seting in pane. Top and right side of Image is getting out of Pane.

I tried to set X and Y Scale using Canvas, but only Image is zooming but not the draw Polygon.

```
getView().getCanvas().setScaleX(getView().getCanvas().getScaleX() * zoomFactor);
getView().getCanvas().setScaleY(getView().getCanvas().getScaleY() * zoomFactor);
```

To zoom image and drawn polygon, I need suggestion of API.

```
    private void setImageAndCanvas() { 
                scrollPane = new ScrollPane(); 
                anchorPane = new AnchorPane(); 
                canvas = new Canvas(screenWidth/2, screenHeight-120); 
                gridLines = new ArrayList<Line>(); 
                imageSections = new ArrayList<Polygon>(); 
                scrollPane.setContent(anchorPane); 
                anchorPane.getChildren().add(canvas); 
                scrollPane.setPrefSize(screenWidth/2, screenHeight-120); 
        }

`public void setCanvas(Canvas canvas, Image img){
        graphicsContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    }`

    private void zoom(double zoomFactor) {
        zoomWidth.set(zoomWidth.get() * zoomFactor);
        zoomHeight.set(zoomHeight.get() * zoomFactor);
        getView().getAnchorPane().setScaleX(getView().getAnchorPane().getScaleX() * zoomFactor);
        getView().getAnchorPane().setScaleY(getView().getAnchorPane().getScaleY() * zoomFactor);
        zoomCounter = zoomFactor>1 ? ++zoomCounter: --zoomCounter;
        if (zoomCounter > 0 && zoomCounter < 3) {
            getView().getZoomIn().setDisable(false);
            getView().getZoomOut().setDisable(false);
        }
    }

    public void zoomOutAction(ActionEvent event) {
        zoom(1/zoomFactor);
        event.consume();
    }

    private void drawAllImageSections(){
        if(getView().getImageNameTablePane().getSelectedItem()!=null){
            String imageName = getView().getImageNameTablePane().getSelectedItem().getImageName();
            List<QiImageSectionPoint> polygonPoints = getModel().showAllImageSection(imageName);
            if(!polygonPoints.isEmpty()){
                List<Double> allPointsList = new ArrayList<Double>();
                double resizeWidthPercent = ((getView().getScreenWidth()/2)-500)/5;
                double resizeHeightPercent = ((getView().getScreenHeight()-120)-500)/5;
                polygon = new Polygon();
                for(int i = 0; i<polygonPoints.size(); i++){
                    int imageSectionId = polygonPoints.get(i).getImageSectionId();
                    if((i+1)<polygonPoints.size() && imageSectionId == polygonPoints.get(i+1).getImageSectionId()){
                        allPointsList.add((double) polygonPoints.get(i).getPointX()+((polygonPoints.get(i).getPointX()*resizeWidthPercent)/100));
                        allPointsList.add((double) polygonPoints.get(i).getPointY()+((polygonPoints.get(i).getPointY()*resizeHeightPercent)/100));
                    }else{
                        allPointsList.add((double) polygonPoints.get(i).getPointX()+((polygonPoints.get(i).getPointX()*resizeWidthPercent)/100));
                        allPointsList.add((double) polygonPoints.get(i).getPointY()+((polygonPoints.get(i).getPointY()*resizeHeightPercent)/100));
                        polygon.getPoints().setAll(allPointsList);
                        polygon.setFill(null);
                        polygon.setStroke(lineColor);
                        polygon.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth);
                        getView().getImageSections().add(polygon);
                        allPointsList = new ArrayList<Double>();
                        polygon = new Polygon();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(getView().getImageSections()!=null)
        getView().getAnchorPane().getChildren().addAll(getView().getImageSections());
    }
```